# Disable repository updating in fedora

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

Fedora checks all repository for updating when every time i want to install some packages from yum. this is waste of time because i know they are updated!

how could i disable this checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know yum is updated then before going to install go to

**/etc/yum.repos.d** directory and edit 
**/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo**

and make changes in updates. In updates there is a value **enabled** set to 1, so change this to 0.

enabled=value

```
…where value is one of:

0 — Do not include this repository as a package source when performing updates and installs. This is an easy way of quickly turning repositories on and off, which is useful when you desire a single package from a repository that you do not want to enable for updates or installs.

1 — Include this repository as a package source.

Turning repositories on and off can also be performed by passing either the --enablerepo=repo_name or --disablerepo=repo_name option to yum, or through the Add/Remove Software window of the PackageKit utility.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Simply use :

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=your_repo  install packagename
```

You can list repo using :

`yum repolist`

if you want to disable permanent then you have to edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` and disable it manually

Answer (score 2):

The "repo is up to date" check is fast, so it shouldn't be a bother. Going around disabling repositories for the sake of a few seconds *will* exact bloody revenge later...

If you are worried that `yum -y install package-A; yum -y install packge-B; ...` will do checking over and over, just do `yum -y install package-A package-B ...`

BTW, Fedora 18 has the experimental `dnf` yum replacement, *much* faster and accurate. It can be installed in paralell. Works like a charm, but still has some rough edges (when it decides that there are unresolvable conflicts, it just finishes silently without doing anything).

Comment: I know about install multiple package, and also I use `dnf`, but i want just disable checking because it every time download 8 MB for updating repoes.

Comment: That shouldn't be, only the small metadata describing the repository gets downloaded, unless there have been changes. Sure, Fedora 18 has been rather active (as Fedora always is when just released), but that definitely shouldn't happen _every time_.